# android logging not working in one class

Tags: android, logging

I've got a ListActivity class that correctly displays, and I can select list items and things happen as expected. But I have Log.* commands that aren't logging. Other classes that are called after OnClick are correctly logging. For instance, my onCreate has this

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e(MY_DEBUG, "Creating list of actions"); // does not log?!?!?
    setTitle("Choose an action for this widget"); // executes fine
    // do other stuff... works fine
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Heh, I just figured out that it is logging on the phone, but for some reason it is not showing up in Eclipse. Just this one class. Very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Log.i(MY_DEBUG, "Creating list of actions");

Comment: Nope. Still ONLY shows up on my phone. I also tried cleaning the project in eclipse.

Comment: Do you have any filters on? Also try restarting the programming environment as I believe I have had a similar problem in Eclipse several problems where it wouldn't show any log output at all.

Comment: Well, what do you know... restarting Eclipse seems to have fixed it. Very strange. I guess it was just "One Of Those Things".

Answer (score 0):

Also, try changing the tag as it may be a reserved word.

This may not work:
Log.i("PHONE", "checkStatus");

But this will work:
Log.i("PHONE_PROPERTY", "checkStatus");

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.

The solution was:

**Check the imports** and make sure that you are using Android Log and not another lib.

**Right**

import android.util.Log;

**Wrong**

import br.com.thainamonteiro.util.Log;